# Selectively redirect to https, not all pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, https

I have a website that requires some secure pages for logging in, user accounts, form submission etc. but does not need to be secure on most pages.

Certificate purchased and installed on www.mywebsite.com.

I am currently redirecting users to the https by using this C# code in the page_load:

```
    if (!Request.IsLocal && !Request.IsSecureConnection)
    {
        string redirectUrl = Request.Url.ToString().Replace("http:", "https:");
        Response.Redirect(redirectUrl);
    }
```

My concern is that after visiting the secure page and the user clicks on another page, it stays secure rather than going back to http.

I have looked at a number of options including IIS rewrite (it's like a whole other language and too complicated) and coding something globally (redirects every page, not selective).

Is there a simple solution that will allow me to redirect to https on selected pages (about 10 or so pages, or all pages in a particular folder) and then back to http on all others? I'm not the greatest coder in the world, so trying to find something easy to implement and understand.

Comment: SSL across the board is the only safe bet. Partial SSL leaves open a whole range of attack vectors that across-the-board SSL closes. Why do you not want to use SSL across the board?

Comment: Why redirect back to `http`? Is `https` causing a problem? Security aside, it just seems like extra work to code this.

Comment: Thanks. Sounds like it might be the way to go. Thought that because most of the site didn't need to be secure, it was better to limit SSL to data/login pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If any portion of your website requires SSL, then I would strongly recommend that you use SSL throughout.  You would be unnecessarily opening yourself up to potential data loss by doing anything else.  Check out [OWASP Top Ten](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=10&ved=0CGoQFjAJ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fowasptop10.googlecode.com%2Ffiles%2FOWASP%2520Top%252010%2520-%25202010.pdf&rct=j&q=owasp&ei=qleYTsbVI7LH0AGrlN3eBA&usg=AFQjCNGQYQo-TFTnCAbnP7dSN8FTd5W99Q&sig2=LR4SmKmIkXbas0V6xgp31A&cad=rja) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

you can use HTTP Handlers to solve this issues instead of having the code on each page load